# Custom input causes error while the same input given in the runtime works in Python

Tags: python

In the following code, if the input is given as text, it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 6, in <module>
    u,v=map(int,input().split(" "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

But for the same input given in the runtime, the code works.

**Please help me identify the error. Thank you.**

```
Input:
14 12
0 1
0 4 
0 2
1 3
1 4
3 5
5 6
5 7
6 8
2 11
11 10
9 13
```

```
node, edge = map(int, input().split(" "))

adjList = [[] for i in range(node + 1)]

for i in range(edge):
    u, v = map(int, input().split(" "))
    adjList[u].append(v)
    adjList[v].append(u)

print("Adjacency list unweighted:")

for i in range(edge):
    print(i, " ---> ", end=" ")
    for j in range(len(adjList[i])):
        print(adjList[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: How are you feeding the input to your program? Manually typing it or through a file?

Comment: What output do you get when you specify the input from the runtime?

Comment: Try `u,v=map(int,input().strip().split(" "))`. Could also be that your last line is an empty line.

Comment: Dear @drum, I got my problem solved. Actually there was an extra space in the input which entailed the trouble. Thank you so much for your kindness to reply me promptly.